# Webpack rebuild is slow using webpack-dev-middleware when building stylus

Tags: webpack-2, webpack-style-loader, webpack-dev-middleware

I'm using webpack 2, with the `webpack-dev-middleware`

```
 {
    test: /\.styl$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'stylus-loader',
        options: {
          use: [nib()],
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
    use: [ {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        publicPath: '/dist/'
      }
    } ]
  }
```

Relevant server code:

```
let compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: ('/dist/')
}));
```

On the initial build (either using `webpack` from the console, or on first running my server) the whole process takes ~2000ms. Changing `.js` files doesn't take long at all (<200ms), but changing stylus files takes a very long time (>90s). If I make a change to the stylus then manually trigger a rebuild with `webpack` it's really quick, but ideally I'd like the watch to do its magic and for my css to be reloaded in place quickly...

Any ideas why the rebuild is taking such a long with stylus, or how I can debug the issue?